# Splitting address into columns with street name, number and letter

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, address

I have got this column and I want to divide the name, numbers and extra character.

[image: table information]

```
'De waterman 13a' -> 'De waterman' | '13' | 'a'
```

So I need a column with `De waterman` a column with `13` and a column with `a`
and if a field does not have an extra character, it is `NULL`.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

Probably *regex* functions will be helpful. (Various approaches would be possible).

One example:

leftside: `regexp_replace("straat", '(\\s\\d.*$)', '')`

numbers: `regexp_substr("straat", '(\\d+)')`

rightside: `regexp_replace("straat", '(^.*\\s\\d+)', '')`

[image]